# how to show more decimals in sas

Tags: sas

I used reg or robustreg procedure and get a table of parameter estimates, however, one of the coefficient is .0016, it's a very important coefficient, since I don't want to divide the value by 100 to get better data, is there any way to let sas include more decimals in the above procedure (reg/robustreg)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Use `ODS OUTPUT` to get the results into a data set
2. `format` your resulting output using `proc print`  to get the precision to display as you want it.

See the [SAS knowledgebase](http://support.sas.com/kb/37/106.html) for an example (using Parameter Estimates).